# Large number of dependent objects as constructor parameters

Tags: php, interface, dependency-injection

I just learned about dependency injection. But I come across this problem: because some of my class's dependent objects can be **very large number**, passing all of them to the class constructor can be very long and not clear, example,

```
interface FooInterface { 
    function fooMethod(); 
} 

class Foo implements FooInterface { 
    function fooMethod(){
        return 'Foo';
    } 
}

class Boo
{
    public $foo;

    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo) // This one is ok because it depends on one object only,
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

class BooFactory
{
    public static function create()
    {
        return new Boo(new Foo);
    }
}

$a = new BooFactory;
$b = $a->create();
var_dump($b->foo->fooMethod());
```

What if it depends on lots of objects,

```
class Boo
{
        public function __construct(FooInterface $foo, TooInterface $boo, PooInterface $poo, etc, etc ,etc, etc, etc) 
        {
        //
         }
}
```

It looks too much don't you think? Or is it normal? Or what else should I do instead?

Comment: This is a problem that [Dependency Injection Containers](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/07/07/dependency-injection-moving-from-basics-to-container/) (such as [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) or [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.fr/PHP-DI/)) are designed to handle

Comment: If you have so many dependencies that this becomes a problem, this is a strong signal that you're violation SRP (the Single Responsibility Principle) and you may want to split up into multiple classes.

Comment: @NikiC: how can I split it up into multiple classes? For instance, it is a controller class that requires these classes - `Article`, `Nav`, `Auth`, etc in it to get a page loaded on request.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is actually has a hard dependency (i.e. not an optional dependency) on all those objects, then it's valid to do this.  If some of the dependencies are optional (e.g. Maybe you can inject a logger, but if it's not present you just don't perform any logging), then consider removing them from the constructor and using setter injection instead.

Setter injection is where you'd add the `$foo` property to your class as normal, but omit it from the constructor's parameters.  Then you'd provide a `setFoo(Foo $foo)` method to your class so that you can inject a `Foo` instance if required.

When a class has a very long list of arguments, it can be a "code smell" that your class is trying to do too much and possibly not following the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  If your class is trying to do too much, consider refactoring your code into a number of smaller classes that consume each other.

Comment: Thanks. What is `setter injection`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a quick paragraph on setter injection.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the edit. `If your class is trying to do too much, consider refactoring your code into a number of smaller classes that consume each other.` how can I split it up into smaller multiple classes? For instance, it is a controller class that requires these classes - `Article`, `Nav`, `Auth`, etc in it to get a page loaded on request.

Comment: If it's a controller class, then it can be quite normal for it to receive lots of classes as dependencies some times.  If it's getting out-of-hand, consider splitting your controller up into multiple controllers, if the actions are each quite different.

Comment: By the way, how can I make these dependencies into setter injections? please take a look on my new post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068059/a-controller-that-might-violate-single-responsibility-principle

Comment: @tealou: that question is answered above - use the set method that Chris has illustrated.