# A controller that might violate Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, php-5.5

Referring to this comment,

> When a class has a very long list of arguments, it can be a "code
>   smell" that your class is trying to do too much and possibly not
>   following the single responsibility principle. If your class is trying
>   to do too much, consider refactoring your code into a number of
>   smaller classes that consume each other.

What should I do about this controller class below - is it "trying to do too much"?

```
class Controller
{
    public $template;
    public $translation;
    public $auth;
    public $article;
    public $nav;

    public function __construct(Database $connection, $template) 
    {
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->translation = new Translator($connection);
        $this->nav = new Nav($connection);
        $this->article = new Article($connection);
        $this->auth = new Auth($connection);
    }

    public function getHtml() 
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])) 
        {
            $item = $this->article->getRow(['url' => 'home','is_admin' => $this->auth->is_admin]);
            include $this->template->path;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I break it up into smaller classes - if it is a controller that holds these basic classes that I need to output a page?

And what should I do so that it is follows the principle of [dependency injection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146)?

Comment: Two parameters is fine. However all those instantiations should probably be parameters either to the constructor, or to separate setters.

Comment: @halfer: thanks. Yes `all those instantiations` are ugly in my controller, how can I make them separate setters so that I can call them in my controller class?

Comment: @halfer: if I make them `parameters either to the constructor`, then it is `a class has a very long list of arguments, it can be a "code smell" that your class is trying to do too much and possibly not following the single responsibility principle.` isn't?

Comment: (Whilst code formatting looks nice, it's not very readable as a general highlighter, either in questions or comments. People interested in editing questions here tend to suggest it is only suitable for inline code).

Comment: Yes, don't add them all to the constructor. The constructor can have maybe 2 or 3 params that are critical to the construction of the object, and the rest should be in setters. A setter is a function that accepts a parameter and stores it in a property, possibly after validating it. You can type-hint them in PHP too, if they are classes or arrays.

Comment: In your case, if all those classes are of equal importance, and if `$connection` is not separately required, I might be inclined to use setters to inject all those classes, and just have `$template` in the constructor.

Comment: Btw, you've asked four questions on this topic (SRP, DI, excess parameters) in the last four hours. One or two questions might have covered all of this. In particular this question is essentially the same problem as your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066292/large-number-of-dependent-objects-as-constructor-parameters).

Comment: @halfer: yes sorry for that. because I am still not sure how to remove those instantiation from the constructor and make them into set methods.

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>**Note:** this will be the short version, because I'm at work. I will elaborate in the evening</sub>

So ... your code has following violations:

- *SRP* (and by extension - SoC): your controller is responsible for validation of input, authorization, data gathering, populating template with data and rendering said template. Also, your `Article` seems to be responsible for both DB abstraction *and* domain logic.
- *LoD*: you are passing the `$connection` *only*  because you need to pass it on to other structures.
- *encapsulation*: all your class attributes have public visibility and can be altered at any point.
- *dependency injection*: while your "controller" has several direct dependencies, you are only passing in the template (which actually shouldn't be managed by controllers in proper MVC).
- *global state*: your code depends on `$_REQUEST` superglobal.
- *loose coupling*: your code is directly tied to the names of classes and the footprint of constructors for those classes, that you initializing in the constructor.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you please explain how can I improve my controller? thanks!

Comment: also, could you please look at my new post here to see if I'm any near correct direction? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/dependency-injection-dependency-injection-containers-in-mvc-web-app/ thanks!

Comment: What does LoD stands for?

Comment: "Law of Demeter"

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** I don't see violation of SRP here, but object composition is slightly broken

From what I see (is this the full class listing?), `$connection` is not directly consumed in the class, so it should not be injected.

And I don't see usage of `$this->translation` and `$this->nav` anywhere. Is that a copy-paste artifact?

Rather inject `$connection`, I would construct `Article` and `Auth` outside of this class, then inject only these, because your controller only uses these directly, not controller. 
So the whole class would be like this:

```
class Controller
{
    private $article;
    private $auth;
    private $template;

    public function __construct(Article $article, Auth $auth, $template) 
    {
        $this->article = $article;
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function getHtml() 
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['url'])) 
        {
            $item = $this->article->getRow(['url' => 'home','is_admin' => $this->auth->is_admin]);
            include $this->template->path;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless your `Article` is a domain object with ActiveRecord pattern, in that case I'd still inject `$connection` and store it in local variable. And create new `Article` object only when you actually need it, i.e. in `getHtml` method.

This way you don't do too much work in constructor, only assigning local variables. Objects composition is handled somewhere else. And if you need to, you can replace implementation of your `Auth`.

Also when you don't do too much work in the constructor, your object graph creation is very cheap. And this is important if you use some sort of DI container, when a lot of objects must be created at the same time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. if I follow this pattern, my the injections in my constructor would be very long for certain controllers.

Comment: for controllers with too many dependencies, that is a definite code smell and possible SRP violation. Not in this sample though.